# SQL, limiting total rows by deleting the one with the lowest value

Tags: mysql, sql, min, sql-delete

I'm trying to make a high score list in a MySQL database, just 3 columns: id, name, and score. The table is called Highscores. I tried using this code:

```
DELETE FROM Highscores WHERE
Score = (SELECT min(Score) FROM Highscores)
AND (SELECT count(*) FROM Highscores) > 10;
```

But it gives this error:

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'Highscores' for update in FROM clause
```

How can I delete the row with the lowest value, only if there are more than 10 rows? There could possibly be more than one row with the lowest value, but I only want one to be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete from highscores where id = (select * from (
select id from highscores order by score desc limit 10,1) as t)
```

Another approach to keep only 10 greatest scores

```
delete from highscores where id in (select * from (
select id from highscores order by score desc limit 10,18446744073709551615) as t)
```

Comment: When I try to do either of these, it gives the error "The table "highscores" does not exist".

Comment: That's because you just need to capitalize Highscores. Don't just copy and paste. Read it first

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you could just create a view with high scores.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stored procedure:

This runs only once

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Sanitize_Highscores`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `Sanitize_Highscores`() READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  DECLARE numrows int DEFAULT 0;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO numrows FROM Highscores;
  if numrows>10 THEN
    DELETE FROM Highscores ORDER BY Score LIMIT 1;
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

and this replaces your query

```
CALL Sanitize_Highscores
```

Comment: This only deletes one and doesn't check that there's more than 10 values in the table still.

Comment: This does not address the issue of only proceeding if there are more than 10 rows.

Comment: I was working on it, when I realized I had saved a much too short version (which you saw) - sorry, cut&paste error.

Comment: I tried your original unfinished post, DELETE FROM Highscores ORDER BY Score LIMIT 1; and added 10 empty highscores to start with, so that it would add one, then delete one, since there will never be less than 10, but for some reason it deletes the most recent addition. I will try this version. Where do I put the procedure code?

Comment: The DELETE statement (which is now part of the stored procedure) deletes thi lowest score, which is what I thought your original code was meant to do. The procedure definition goes directly to the database - depending on what your environment is, you can use the mysql command line client, phpmyadmin, a choice of GUI tools and a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a temporary table and use that in your SELECT calls.